# Сущность не сохраняется в БД

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-mvc

UPD: Добавление не происходит из-за циклической зависимости. Не могу понять как это исправить, при этом на диаграмме БД ее не наблюдается, проблема скорее всего в связях. При ручном добавлении car_entity_id возникает огромная циклическая зависимость.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть две сущности: владелец и машина.
У владельца одно из полей - список с машинами, связь один ко многим.

На контроллере через сервис вызываю метод добавления машины по Id к владельцу. Прохожусь в дебаге, получает записи корректно, но не сохраняет запись в сущность. Сохраняю через JPA репозиторий.

Работаю через сваггер, добавление происходит успешно (получаю код 200), но добавление в БД в сущность не происходит.

Метод в сервисе:

```
    public void addCarToOwnerById(Integer carId, Integer ownerId) {
    var optionalOwnerEntity = ownersRepository.findById(ownerId);
    var ownerEntity = optionalOwnerEntity.orElseGet(OwnerEntity::new);

    var optionalCarEntity = carsRepository.findById(carId);
    var carEntity = optionalCarEntity.orElseGet(CarEntity::new);

    var carEntities = ownerEntity.getCarEntities();
    carEntities.add(carEntity);
    ownerEntity.setCarEntities(carEntities);

    ownersRepository.save(ownerEntity);
}
```

Сущность машины:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Cars")
public class CarEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "propSeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "propSeq", sequenceName = "property_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    private Integer Id;
    private String number;
    private String brand;
    private Integer driversQuantity;

    @ManyToOne
    private OwnerEntity carEntity;
```

Сущность владельца:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Owners")
public class OwnerEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "propSeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "propSeq", sequenceName = "property_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    private Integer Id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "carEntity")
    private List<CarEntity> carEntities;
```

p.s. На всякий случай прикладываю картинку с дебага и таблицы + диаграмму
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас эти сущности уже в бд, о чем речь?

Comment: @First Sin, сущности есть, а добавление значений не работает. В частности, модель машины не добавляется в список моделей машин у владельца

Comment: В таблице машин есть поле car_entity_id,оно отвечает за сущность владельца, вот оно как бы и должно добавиться

Comment: Там, где у вас аннотация `@ManyToOne` напишите еще `@JoinColumn(name = "car_entity_id")`

Comment: @FirstSin не помогает. Проблема в том, что если я назначаю эту же сущность, то у меня конечно же возникает переполнение: carEntity.setCarEntity(entity), а если так не делать, то ничего не добавляется. В общем, я уже устал)
Проще наверное сделать связь много ко многим >_<